# To draw polygon on google map with MapKit framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I wanted to display Google map in a map view on which I want to draw a polygon/circle.

Any advice?

Answer (score 6):

The way I'm reading your question is that you want to **programmatically** draw the polygon on the map.  For this, consult the [Apple docs on MapKit.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW15)

You don't need to add transparent views over the MapKit map (`MKMapView`).  You create an *overlay* object, in this case an `MKPolygon`.  (in the following example, the variable `map` will be the `MKMapView` instance owned by the view controller that you put this code in):

```objc
CLLocationCoordinate2D  points[4];

points[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.000512, -109.050116);
points[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.002371, -102.052066);
points[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.993076, -102.041981);
points[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.99892, -109.045267);

MKPolygon* poly = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:points count:4];
poly.title = @"Colorado";

[map addOverlay:poly];
```

Then, if you want to customize the look (colors, stroke, etc.) of the overlay, you implement the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol in the view controller you have that owns the `MKMapView` object and provide an implementation of `mapView:viewForOverlay`:

```objc
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
    {
        MKPolygonView* aView = [[[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:(MKPolygon*)overlay] autorelease];
 
        aView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        aView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        aView.lineWidth = 3;
 
        return aView;
    }
 
    return nil;
}
```

Of course, always remember to actually assign the map instance's delegate to your view controller (MKMapViewDelegate), either in the interface builder, or in code (e.g. `viewDidLoad`).

Comment: And, of course, for circles, you would use `MKCircle` instead of `MKPolygon`

Answer (score 1):

I used ideas from this persons blog post to accomplish this.  It basically involves adding a transparent view over the map.  The map then allows you to convert locations to points on the view.  Let me know if the site does not help you and I can try and dig up an example from my code.

http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65